# How to see the format of the space in the Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I have a space in Tarantool and want to see the format.

I've overlooked the documentation but didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view a schema of the space via Box API:

```
box.space.test:format()
```

Possible result:

```
---
- [{'name': 'surname', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'age', 'type': 'any'}]
...
```

Read more about it [in the documentation.](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_space/#box-space-format)